# is possible using slideDown and delegate togather in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

is it possible to combine slideDown method with delegate or live method in jquery to apply slideDown method to later  added elemenets in page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, [`.slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) is just a method, for example:

```
$("#container").delegate(".toggleButton", "click", function() {
  $(this).next().slideDown();
});
```

If you want to slide down content as it's added, do that in your AJAX `success` callback, for example:

```
$.ajax({ //options...
  success: function(data) {
    $(data).appendTo("#container").hide().slideDown();
  }
});
```